# Does open(filepath, O_WRONLY|O_EXCL) return a value if filepath exists?

Tags: c

I know that `open(filepath, O_WRONLY|O_EXCL)` will fail if `filepath` exists, but does it return anything?

Now say if I want to know if a file exists, and would like to print a message if it does, should I include the `O_EXCL` flag in the `open()` command above?

Edit: I guess I made a mistake, and I was supposed to use `open(filepath, O_CREAT|O_EXCL)`

Comment: `open(filepath, O_CREAT|O_EXCL)` is incorrect too: it should be `open(filepath, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644)`

Answer (score 3):

`open(filepath, O_WRONLY|O_EXCL)` will not fail if `filepath` exists, it will fail if it does not exist or if you do not have write access.

`O_EXCL` should only be used with `O_CREAT` and an extra argument must then be passed to specify the mode bits for the file to create:

```
int hd = open(filepath, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644);
```

`hd` will have a negative value in case of failure and `errno` will be set to indicate the error cause. Use `perror()` to report the failure with an explicit error message.

You can also test file existence and write access with `access()`, but it is not appropriate for your use case as the file could be created by a concurrent process between the test with `access` and the call to `open` (among other reasons).

Comment: Note that `access` is not a good tool here or anywhere because (1) it has TOCTOU issues, and (2) it uses real uid/gid not effective uid/gid.

Answer (score 1):

An important note from the [manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> In general, the behavior of O_EXCL is undefined if it is used
> without O_CREAT.  There is one exception: on Linux 2.6 and
> later, O_EXCL can be used without O_CREAT if pathname refers
> to a block device.

So barring one use case, your command invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up. So is it true that if I try to use ```open(filepath, O_CREAT|O_EXCL)``` on a filepath that already exists, it returns a negative value due to error?

Answer (score 0):

If `open` fails for any reason, it will return -1 and set `errno` to indicate the cause. The details are in your open(2) manual page. Type `man 2 open` in any Unixy system.

Answer (score 0):

from the MAN page for `open()`:

O_EXCL Ensure that this call creates the file: if this flag  is  speci‐
fied  in  conjunction with O_CREAT, and pathname already exists,
then open() fails with the error EEXIST.

```
          When these two flags are specified, symbolic links are not  fol‐
          lowed: if pathname is a symbolic link, then open() fails regard‐
          less of where the symbolic link points.

          In general, the behavior of O_EXCL is undefined if  it  is  used
          without  O_CREAT.   There  is  one  exception:  on Linux 2.6 and
          later, O_EXCL can be used without O_CREAT if pathname refers  to
          a  block  device.   If  the block device is in use by the system
          (e.g., mounted), open() fails with the error EBUSY.
```

Therefore, your premise that it fails if the file already exist is not quite correct.

However, when it fails: (per the MAN page)

```
open(), openat(), and creat() return the new file descriptor, or -1  if
   an error occurred (in which case, errno is set appropriately).
```